# Show that the ellipsoid is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convexity-inequality, ellipsoids

> Show that an ellipsoid $$\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \ : \ x^TAx+2b^Tx+c\le 0\},$$ where $A\in \mathbb{S}^n_+$, is a convex set.

Comment: Any sublevel set of a convex function is convex.

Comment: Why is this function convex?

Comment: @abbasly Just compute the Hessian matrix of $F(x)=x^T A x + 2b^T x+c$ ... It is a (constant) positive definite matrix, which implies that $F$ is convex.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{S}^n_+$ the set of symmetric positive definite $n \times n$ matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  $x,y$ on the ellipsoid let $z=y-x.$

For $t\in \Bbb R$ let $F(t)=(x+tz)^T A (x+tz)+2b^T (x+tz)+c.$

We have $$F(t)=t^2(z^T A z) +t(z^T Ax + x^T A z+2b^Tz)+ F(0).$$ With $x,y,z $ fixed, we have $F''(t)=2z^T A z\ge 0.$